# C# WPF Image + 2 Texts in a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a WPF a similar to the one in the image so that i can `Bind the Image Source, The Movie Name & The Category` (Ignore the left side)

[image: http://prntscr.com/alb7qs]

Is this a ListView ? I tried many different combos but i couldn't make it as the one above.

Also, since it is related to that question, how i can have dynamically column number based on the Window size? For example in the image above the columns are 5, but i want it to be dynamically based on the Window Pixel/Size. Is this possible?

Comment: By question marks: (1) ListView - I doubt. ListBox more probably. Plus custom inner itemspanel. ItemsControl for sure. (2) many ways, the simplest: wrappanel+constant tile width. It will pack as much items in a 'row' as possible, hence it will look like dynamic columns (3) yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of work to learn how to do it in a ListView. I'm not sure if the widths can be dynamic (based on each image width) but I've done it similarly to how Windows Explorer Icons views does it. So extra large, large, etc.

A good starting point for this is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859

But it's a tonne of work. Probably 2 or 3 months. They only give you bits and pieces and it's a variety of C# and VB.

Comment: ye no problem if it can be done with list boxes. I just made a question if it is listview...

Answer (score 0):

You might want a more low-level ItemsControl.

Try the example from here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

The one that might work for you is the WrapPanel as it will change the wrapping / layout based on the available container size and the item size.

Your Image and Text controls with bindings would go in the DataTemplate.